# How to export strings from Java (Android) to MS Word

Tags: java, android, string, ms-word, export

I want to know how to export typed strings to a word document file.

The application I'm trying to make should be simple; User has his application on his Android phone and he types in some text.

It will have few PlainText and MultilineText text fields, in which the user will be able to type, whatever he wants.

So, when a user connects his mobile to the computer, he should be able to click some button and 'generate report'.
That way, all the text he typed in should be transformed into a word doc.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use some sort of java library for Microsoft Office. Take a look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for this. Here's [an example](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/CreateWordDocument) of using Apache POI.

As a side note, I would also recommend that the user doesn't have to actually connect their device to the computer, but rather make an export feature which will create the Word Document and they can e-mail it or share it in some other way. This would improve your User Experience :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It was realy helpful!

I have another question now.
I dont know how to include the poi library into an android project.

When I want to include it in the regular Java pproject, I would right click on the project, in Eclipse -> Build path -> Add external Archives

How am I supposed to do it in an Android project?

Comment: Please accept this answer and ask that in another question. I would be happy to help you in that question :-)

Comment: Allright.
Here is the link to another question, then :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439199/how-to-include-poi-library-into-an-android-project