# How to include POI library into an Android project?

Tags: android, apache-poi

How to include the poi library into an android project?
When I want to include it in the regular Java project, I would right click on the project, in Eclipse -> Build path -> Add external Archives

How am I supposed to do it in an Android project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put jar in libs folder and then Project -> Properies -> Java Buid Path -> Add JARs -> Select jar of your library from libs folder -> OK.

Answer (score 0):

You should put jar in libs folder (the same level as res or src folder) and do Eclipse -> Build path -> Add external Archives